# How to add multiple line of output one by one to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

This might be a very basic question but I was not able to find solution. I have a script:

If I run `w | awk '{print $1}'`  in command line in my server I get:

```
f931
smk591
sc271
bx972
gaw844
mbihk988
laid640
smk59
ycc951
```

Now I need to use this list in my bash script one by one and manipulate some operation on them. I need to check their group and print those are in specific group. The command to check their group is `id username`. How can I save them or iterate through them one by one in a loop.

what I have so far is

```
tmp=$(w | awk '{print $1})
```

But it only return first record! Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop, i.e.

```
for user in $(w | awk '{print $1}'); do echo $user; done
```

which in a script would look nicer as:

```
for user in $(w | awk '{print $1}')
do
    echo $user
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Populate an array with the output of the command:

```
$ tmp=( $(printf "a\nb\nc\n") )
$ echo "${tmp[0]}"
a
$ echo "${tmp[1]}"
b
$ echo "${tmp[2]}"
c
```

Replace the `printf` with your command (i.e. `tmp=( $(w | awk '{print $1}') )`) and `man bash` for how to work with bash arrays.

For a lengthier, more robust and complete example:

```
$ cat ./tstarrays.sh
# saving multi-line awk output in a bash array, one element per line
# See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/ for
# more operations you can perform on an array and its elements.

oSET="$-"; set -f       # save original set flags and turn off globbing
oIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'  # save original IFS and make IFS a newline

array=( $(
    awk 'BEGIN{
        print "the      quick   brown"
        print "    fox jumped\tover\tthe"
        print "lazy    dogs back    "
    }'
) )

IFS="$oIFS"             # restore original IFS value
set +f -$oSET           # restore original set flags

for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++ ));
do
    printf "array[%d] of length=%d: \"%s\"\n" "$i" "${#array[$i]}" "${array[$i]}"
done

printf -- "----------\n"
printf -- "array[@]=\n\"%s\"\n" "${array[@]}"

printf -- "----------\n"
printf -- "array[*]=\n\"%s\"\n" "${array[*]}"
```

.

```
$ ./tstarrays.sh
array[0] of length=22: "the      quick   brown"
array[1] of length=23: "    fox jumped  over    the"
array[2] of length=21: "lazy    dogs back    "
----------
array[@]=
"the      quick   brown"
array[@]=
"    fox jumped over    the"
array[@]=
"lazy    dogs back    "
----------
array[*]=
"the      quick   brown     fox jumped  over    the lazy    dogs back    "
```

A couple of non-obvious key points to make sure your array gets populated with exactly what your command outputs:

1. If your command output can contain globbing characters than you should disable globbing before the command (`oSET="$-"; set -f`) and re-enable it afterwards (`set +f -$oSET`).
2. If your command output can contain spaces then set IFS to a newline before the command (`oIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'`) and set it back to it's old value after the command (`IFS="$oIFS"`).

Comment: `saving multi-line awk output in a bash array` I was looking for that. Learned much.

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp=$(w | awk '{print $1}')

while read i
do
    echo "$i"
done <<< "$tmp"
```

Comment: Note that the variable is not necessary.  `w | awk ... | while ...` works just as well.

Comment: and you should always use `while IFS= read -r i` unless you have a specific modification of the input data you're trying to accomplish by not setting `IFS` (e.g. skipping leading blanks) and/or not using `-r` (e.g. interpolating backslashes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xargs` command to do this:

```
w | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' id '{}'
```

With the -I switch, xargs will take each line of its standard input separately, then construct and execute a command line by replacing the specified string `'{}'` in the command line template with the input line

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `who` instead of `w`. Try this out,

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 id
```